# Why can't I start up my express server in my React app?

Tags: node.js, express

I am currently building a portfolio website with React and need to set up a back-end to process requests for an email API I'm using for my contact page. I've installed express as one of my node modules and created a server.js file at the root with the following code:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8080

app.get('/hello', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Very basic start. However when I start my react application, I do not see the "Example app listening on port 8080" logged into my node terminal. I'm not sure what I've done wrong exactly as this is all I've needed in the past to start the server I've built with express although this time I built my react app first and then tried to implement this server so perhaps I missed something. 
Full code is here: https://github.com/caseycling/portfolio

Comment: How exactly do you run `server.js`? By using `node server.js`?

Comment: Works for me using node 12. Which version of node.js are you using?

Comment: If i run node server.js it works but then i cant run my react app with npm start